# sedとawkを用いてping平均時間を求めたい（OSX bash）

Tags: macos, sh, sed, awk

```
#!/bin/bash
ipaddr="10.0.1.1"
count=10

echo "Ping to: $ipaddr"
echo "Ping count: $count"
echo "Ping average[ms]:"

#Pingコマンドを実行し、結果をファイルに出力
ping -c $count $ipaddr > ping.txt

#time=??ms部分をsedで取り出し（|¥で改行）
sed -n "s/^.*time=¥(.*¥) ms/¥1/p" ping.txt |¥
#行数(NR)で割って、平均を求める
awk '{sum+=$1} END{print sum/NR}' > ping2.txt
```

これを実行すると、エラーになってしまいます。

/Users/hoge/Ping/ping.sh: line 14: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/Users/hoge/Ping/ping.sh: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Pingの結果は下記のようなフォーマットで返ってきています。

```
$ ping -c 10 10.0.1.1
PING 10.0.1.1 (10.0.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=3.019 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=1.976 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=1.973 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=2.005 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=255 time=1.959 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=255 time=1.415 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=255 time=1.977 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=255 time=1.976 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=255 time=1.453 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=255 time=2.000 ms
```

Comment: 勝手に編集させていただきました。変更場所は最後の awk でシングルクォートが閉じていなかった箇所です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。おかげさまで記載していたエラーは解消しました。

ただ、まだ下記エラーが出ます。
line 13: ¥: command not found

Comment: ¥ がバックスラッシュとして認識されていない様です。まぁ、バックスラッシュを付けなくても継続行と見なされますので、削除してしまっても良いかと思います。

Comment: コメントで解決してたw。 私的には、 `¥`(U+00A5) と `\ ` (U+005C) のキャラクタコードが異なるのを知らなかったのでそこで驚きました・・・

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問に書いてあったエラーが出ないので、 `line 13: ¥: command not found` の問題を。

```
sed -n "s/^.*time=¥(.*¥) ms/¥1/p" ping.txt |¥
```

の行末の `¥` が不要です。

```
#!/bin/bash
ipaddr="ja.stackoverflow.com"
count=5

echo "Ping to: $ipaddr"
echo "Ping count: $count"
echo "Ping average[ms]:"

#Pingコマンドを実行し、結果をファイルに出力
ping -c $count $ipaddr > ping.txt

#time=??ms部分をsedで取り出し（|¥で改行後、行数(NR)で割って、平均を求める）
cat ping.txt | sed -n "s/^.*time=\(.*\) ms/\1/p" ping.txt |
    awk '{sum+=$1} END{print sum/NR}' > ping2.txt
```

それから、次回 bash スクリプトを書くときは、ファイル先頭行の

```
#!/bin/bash
```

を、

```
#!/bin/bash -v
```

に変えてから始めてみてください。気持ち問題に気付きやすくなるはずです。

Answer (score 4):

回答ではないのですが、質問者様が実行したい処理は以下の様なものではないでしょうか。

```
#!/bin/bash

ipaddr="10.0.1.1"
count=10

echo "Ping to: $ipaddr"
echo "Ping count: $count"
echo -n "Ping average[ms]: "

ping -c $count $ipaddr | 
  awk 'BEGIN{FS="(time=|ms)"}/time=/{sum+=$2;i++}END{print sum/i}' |
  tee ping.txt
```

ただ、Mac OSX デフォルトの awk(BSD由来) では期待通りの結果が得られるのかどうかは不明です(awk の FS 変数に正規表現が使用できるのかどうか？)。

追記:

round trip time の平均値が分かればよい、ということであれば、以下の様にもできます(bash 前提)。

```
$ ping -c 10 10.0.1.1 | tail -1 | tee >(cut -d/ -f5)
```

追記その2:

ご質問の主旨からは外れますが、ping の結果(rtt)を整形して表示する awk スクリプトも載せておきます。

```
#!/bin/bash

ipaddr="10.0.1.1"
count=10

echo "Ping to: $ipaddr"
echo "Ping count: $count"
echo "Round trip time:"

ping -c "$count" "$ipaddr" | tail -1 | 
  awk '
    BEGIN{RS=" *= *|\n";FS="/|^rtt *| *ms$"}
    {
      if ($1 == "") {for(i=1;i<NF;i++){$i=$(i+1)};NF--}
      for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){rtt[NR][i] = $i}
    }
    END{
      for(i=1;i<NF;i++){
        printf("%5s = %.3f ms\n", rtt[NR-1][i], rtt[NR][i])
      }
    }
  '
```

Answer (score 1):

ありがとうございました。無事動作しました。

```
#!/bin/bash -v
ipaddr="10.0.1.1"
count=10

echo "Ping to: $ipaddr"
echo "Ping count: $count"
echo "Ping average[ms]:"

#Pingコマンドを実行し、結果をファイルに出力
ping -c $count $ipaddr > ping.txt


#time=??ms部分をsedで取り出し（|¥で改行後、行数(NR)で割って、平均を求める）
cat ping.txt | sed -n "s/^.*time=\(.*\) ms/\1/p" ping.txt |
awk '{sum+=$1} END{print sum/NR}' > ping2.txt
cat ping2.txt
```

こちらも目から鱗でした。たしかにbashなのでこれで十分ですね。
     $ ping -c 10 10.0.1.1 | tail -1 | tee >(cut -d/ -f5)

Answer (score 1):

awkを使ったワンライナーの例を２つ紹介します。

例１

```
$ ping -c 5 ja.stackoverflow.com | awk -F"/" '{print} END {printf("\n---\navg: %s\n", $5)}'
PING ja.stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.16): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 198.252.206.16: icmp_seq=0 ttl=46 time=334.556 ms
64 bytes from 198.252.206.16: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=370.802 ms
64 bytes from 198.252.206.16: icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=500.598 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
64 bytes from 198.252.206.16: icmp_seq=3 ttl=46 time=1174.977 ms
64 bytes from 198.252.206.16: icmp_seq=4 ttl=46 time=555.384 ms

--- ja.stackoverflow.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 334.556/587.263/1174.977/304.845 ms

---
avg: 587.263
```

例２

```
$ ping -c 5 ja.stackoverflow.com | awk '$2=="bytes" {split($7, arr, "="); i++; sum += arr[2]; print arr[2]} END {print "--"; print sum / i}'
342.768
327.314
334.996
392.753
324.054
--
344.377
```